# Повтор подстрок

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Записать строку, алфавит которой состоит из 4 букв(a,b,c,d), в форме с количеством повторов. Вложенность подстрок приветствуется.

Примеры:

```
abbbcddaa становится ab3cd2a2
abcabcabcd -> (abc)3d
abbabb -> (ab2)2
ddddabcabccabccabccabc -> d4ab(cabc)4
```

Сам начал делать, но что-то сложность начинает расти. Как решить наиболее оптимально?

```py
def compress(s):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        for i in range(j+1, len(s)):
            if s[j] == s[i]:
                diff = i - j
                ssum = 1
                for k in range(i, len(s), diff):
                    if s[j:i] != s[k:k+diff]:
                        break
                    ssum += 1
                if ssum > 1:
                    print(s[j:i], ssum, "times")
    return s
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, что тут считается подстроками?

Comment: что вы ожидаете на выходе `abbabb`: `(abb)2` или `(ab2)2` ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, второй вариант - `(ab2)2`

Comment: @Jack_oS, [подстрока](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: То есть вы желаете получить самую короткую результирующую строку, которая получена сжатием повторяющихся подряд подстрок?

Comment: @EzikBro, да, верно.

Comment: Под сложностью вы имеете в виду вычислительную, BigO и все такое? Что значит, что она начинает расти? Для конкретного алгоритма асимптотика равна определенной функции, а не растет куда-то. И какую сложность вы желаете получить?

Comment: @EzikBro, принимаются все ответы, решением будет наиболее оптимальное по скорости.

Comment: Также, почему в примере n1tr0xs'a вы ожидаете именно второй вариант? Они ведь одинаковы по своей длине. Какой именно критерий задает однозначность ответа при равной длине?

Comment: Что именно делает ваша функция? Она не возвращает результат, который вы ожидаете в примерах. Что она принтует и есть ли у вас функция, которая именно решает поставленную задачу, хоть и не оптимально?

Comment: @EzikBro, если вам не интересно искать решение, не ищите.

Comment: Если бы мне было не интересно, то я бы не уточнял детали. Это вопрос банального уважения сформулировать задачу полно и корректно. Вдобавок все еще существует вероятность, что это задача с какой-то олимпиады или какого-то соревнования, которую вы не смогли решить самостоятельно и теперь просите помощи у сообщества. Поэтому я прошу вас предоставить более полные пояснения в корректном виде, добавив их прямо в тело вопроса. Также было бы правильно, если бы вы добавили свой код, который решает поставленную задачу. Если его у вас нет, то как вы планируете банально тестировать наши решения?

Comment: @EzikBro, уважение присутствует, вас никто не оскорблял. Примеры вывода есть. Приведите примеры когда у вас возникают сложности с этой задачей.

Comment: Вы не ответили, почему вы выбрали именно второй вариант в примере n1tr0xs'a. Обе сжатые строки имеют одинаковую длину, поэтому не понятно, как именно вы выбрали нужный ответ.

Comment: @EzikBro, все просто - вложенность приветствуется.